# How to internationalize large formatted text

Tags: c#, xaml, internationalization, windows-phone

I'm making an app with some substantial text. I want this text to be internationalized so I store it in separate text files. This works fine.

The text contains of a few articles, every article has a few paragraphs and some paragraphs contain HTML-like formatting.

The part I'm unsure about is how to get this text in my view? I tried setting the `Xaml` property of a `RichTextBox` but then my text files should contain proper `XAML`. I'd rather not go this way.

Another aproach I took was adding the paragraphs as `TextBlock` to a `StackPanel`. Didn't seem right either.

So, any suggestions how to tackle this? Maybe store it as proper XHTML and then transform it to XAML an inject in a `RichTextBox`?

**EDIT**
The app presents the articles on a pivot control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render your content in HTML via a `WebControl` and the `NavigateToString` method:

```
<Controls:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" />
```

And in the code-behind:

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("projectname;component/article.html", UriKind.Relative));
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(sri.Stream))
{
    String html = stream.ReadToEnd();    
    browser.NavigateToString(html);
}
```

Here is an interesting article about using the `WebBrowser` control: [Windows Phone WebBrowser control tips](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/09/17/windows-phone-webbrowser-control-tips.aspx)

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't satisfy. The drawbacks: I'm presenting the text in a pivot control (whoops, forgot to tell in advance). Using a browser o a pivot page prevents swiping to another page. I worked around that by putting a transparant rectangle above the browser but that is pretty ugly. Next to that: with this solution I have to maintain styles in two places and in two syntaxes. By the way, since my text files are resources I was able to use `browser.NavigateToString(AppResources.MyArticle);` Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, I understand the drawbacks. I have another idea: you could store the content is XAML format in your Resource files, then use XamlReader.Load to load your controls from the string representation into a Container like the Grid control. I can edit my answer if you're interested in that solution.

Comment: I played with your idea and it actually works.  But then it got me thinking: May be I can bind my `PivotItems` to the resources? Tried that, actually works as well, almost. The `PivotItem` now displays the XAML instead of rendering it. So I created a simple XamlToScrollView converter and added it to the binding and everything works like a charm!  Tank you for being my [rubber duck](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking).